# What is an unambiguous variable name for UISwitch, since "switch" is a reserved keyword?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

Xcode won't let me name my IBOutlet "switch", because it's a reserved keyword:

```
@IBOutlet weak var switch: UISwitch!
```

Comment: Personally I use `toggle` most of the times

Comment: I think OP is about to start a war. haha. Personally, I prefer a named switch `namedToggle` because its more descriptive: `aLongNameForToggle.isOn` etc.

Comment: `dasYeOleSwitch`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to name a constant or variable with same name as a reserved keyword.

> Just surround the keyword within (`) backticks

for eg.

```
@IBOutlet weak var `switch`: UISwitch!
```

when using it as a name, However, we should avoid using keywords as names anyway.

Comment: Thanks for this! I knew this is possible. My question was more about a better approach to variable naming.

Answer (score 3):

As always, you should name variables by their meaning not just repeat the class name in lowercase. For example, the following variables have bad naming:

```
let double: Double = 2
let array: [String] = []
```

better names are

```
let scale: Double = 2
let names: [String] = []
```

The same applies to outlets. It's not nice to call `UILabel` just `label`. Better name is `titleLabel` or `usernameLabel`. It's not nice to call `UIImageView` just `imageView`. Better names are `backgroundImageView` or `avatarImageView`.

A good name for `UISwitch` depends on the meaning of the variable. It could be `enabledSwitch` or something similar.

Comment: great advice - nice comment, not an answer (but a naming flame var)

Comment: @Daij-Djan Every style guideline will tell you this. Naming flame vars could be about different things but the fact that you should name variables by their meaning is generally accepted.

Comment: how to best name stuff is on X questions here, 10000s of results on google and in almost all books. SO shouldnt even try to teach this IMO. anway It was obvious Id get burned for this while I didnt even vote :D

Comment: and we dont know the use case.. maybe he got enum CommonControls enum and switch as value :D [granted this is totally unlikely]

Comment: @Daij-Djan There can be long discussion about what is the best name and I don't advise a specific name, however, some names are obviously bad.

Answer (score 1):

Variable naming, while seemingly trivial, can be one of those things that causes endless friction (confusion, tech-debt manifesting as refactoring) not to mention interpersonal conflict.

A simple rule that is helpful to minimise this, is to name UI elements as minimally generically as possible, but no less.

For example, for a UI that contains a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel`, the following would be suitable:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
```

This would avoid specifying the content of an imageView in code as much as possible (as opposed to, say, "avatarImageView" which might need to be refactored when the design changes).

However, should there be multiple elements of the same type, it would become important to disambiguate them:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var detailLabel: UILabel!
```

With regards to the case of a `UISwitch`, where naming the variable "switch" is not possible, following the same logic would be to disambiguate it with a prefix:

```
@IBOutlet weak var settingSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var preferenceSwitch: UISwitch!
```

***Update:** Thanks to @rmaddy for pointing this out!*

Comment: You should take inspiration from `titleLabel` and `detailLabel` and name your switch variable something like `someNounSwitch`.

Comment: great advice - nice comment, not an answer (but a naming flame var)

Answer (score 0):

I never use generic names for controls, mainly because if requirements change for the app, you might need to add another UISwitch to the same view (or view controller). I'll typically use a naming convention that gives a fairly clear understanding of the control:

```
@IBOutlet weak var emailTxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var showPasswordTgl: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var loginBtn: UIButton!
@IBOUtlet weak var loginSectionPnl: UIView!
```

I abbreviate the word "toggle" for switch because I think switch was a bad choice for Apple to name that control. There are many switches in the real world that have more than 2 states, so toggle is more straightforward for a control that's either in the "on" or "off" state. For a basic view, I use an abbreviation for "Panel" because that's how I'll typically use an empty view. Since most visual controls in UIKit derive from a UIView (i.e. UIControl->UIView), to me, it would be too generic a term to abbreviate.

Comment: I agree with everything you said, except the fact tht you rndmly left lettrs out of yr variable names. Turns out Swift compiles and even runs just as fast regardless of character count  The reason I point this out is that it’s a carryover habit from the olden days, and it imposes on future contributors to the codebase to guess meaning. “emailTxt” can get confused with a reference to a string, and Developer2 might prefer “passwordTf”…